# Label Text doesn't update unless i debug or hover over dropdown menu IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

i am stumped about this one.
The code works perfectly it goes through the loop as expected.
It even updates the text.
But the text on the screen won't update unless i am debugging and stepping through the code.
or if i hover over my dropdown menu.

Anyone have a clue on why below code does update the label on the screen?
Mind you this works fine on any other version of IE or any other browser for that matter.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="stuff" CssClass="radiolist" runat="server"> 
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1" Selected="True" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
    var checked = $(".radiolist input:checked").val();
    setCheckBoxText(checked);
});

function setCheckBoxText(option) {
    console.log(option);
    var chk = $(".chkAgree input");
    var lbl = $(".chkAgree label");

    if (option == "1") {
        lbl.text("1");
        chk.attr('checked', false);
        $(".btnNext").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    if(option == "2") {
        lbl.text("2");
        chk.attr('checked', false);
        $(".btnNext").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
</script>
```

Edit, $(function() {}); happens in the Masterpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like i figured out how to fix it.

instead of 
    lbl.text("Different Text");
use
    lbl.html("Different Text");

I don't know why this doesn't work in IE9 but it seems to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Missing start quotation? lbl.text(1");

Comment: Actually that code is fine. i edited my actual code to heavily to make it safe to post on the web.

Comment: I would use currentTarget in your binding just to make sure the right radio button will be changed. Maybe if you console.log the currentTarget you can see how the element changed. This would allow you to see the state of the object without having debug interfere and cause the change to properly happen.

Comment: the console.log shows me the correct item. Also i'm trying to change a label on a completely different object. i'll try currentTarget and see if i can find something else. Thx